# What is running integral?

Tags: integration

My question might be too simple. But I could not find any source giving the answer. Can you please explain the running integral?

Comment: It seems to be an electrical engineering term, used in signals work. I have no idea what it means.

Comment: I have only seen this term in [this Q&A](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/194384/8157)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If
$$S(t) = \int_{-\infty}^ts(\tau)d\tau$$
then $S$ is the running integral of $s$. For example the relation between the functions of accumulated probability and probability density.

Comment: Interesting. I have never seen it in the probability context. Is $t$ usually time? Is that where the name comes from?

Comment: Yes many one-dimensional signals have time as their dimension. I think that is why $t$ is often used as variable.