# Alternate way to prove running average of a convex function is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f(t)$ be a convex function and let $g(t)$ denote its running average. Here $g(t)$ can be shown to be $$g(t) = \int_{0}^{1}f(ts)ds$$ Here, $g(t)$ is to be proved to be convex. A nice answer to this question is already posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194384/running-average-of-a-convex-function-is-convex). My question is can this statement be proved by the following steps :
(1) A convex function determines an epigraph
(2) The epigraph is a convex set. Under the above integral operator  which is linear , convexity is preserved
(3) We hence get another epigraph which determines the convex function $g(t)$

Are all my steps correct and can convexity of $g(t)$ be proved in this way ?

Comment: One immediate observation is linearity of an operator T implies that -T is also linear, so convexity does not follow from linearity.

Comment: If $T:U\rightarrow V$ is a linear function and $\mathcal{X} \subseteq U$ is convex, then indeed the following set is convex: $$T(\mathcal{X}) = \{v \in V : v=T(u) \mbox{ for some $u \in U$}\}$$  and so linear functions preserve convex sets.  But in your above argument, you start with a convex set (being the epigraph) and then you introduce a "linear operator," but what is it linear on?  The integral seems to be a linear transformation  on functions, not points of a set.

Comment: Aaah got it. Thanks.