# If ‎$‎f^\prime‎$ ‎is ‎convex then‎ ‎what ‎can ‎be ‎said ‎about ‎$‎f$ ‎?‎ ‎

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

‎Let ‎$‎f‎$ ‎be a‎ ‎differentiable ‎real ‎function ‎on ‎‎$‎[1, +\infty)‎$ such  that ‎‎‎$‎f^\prime‎‎$ ‎is ‎convex.‎

Now,‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎what ‎can ‎be ‎said ‎about ‎‎$‎f‎$ ‎?‎
‎

I know that, if ‎$‎f‎$ ‎is ‎differentiable ‎on ‎‎$‎(a, b)‎$‎, then ‎$‎f‎$ ‎is ‎convex ‎if ‎and ‎only ‎if ‎‎$‎f^\prime‎‎$ ‎is ‎increasing.

Also, ‎if ‎$‎f^{‎\prime‎‎\prime‎}‎$ ‎exists ‎on ‎‎$‎(a, b)‎$‎, then ‎$‎f‎$ ‎is ‎convex ‎if ‎and ‎only ‎if ‎‎$‎f^{‎\prime‎‎\prime‎}‎\geq ‎0‎$‎.‎
‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎

‎

Comment: In what sense do you want something said about $f$?
if $f'$ is convex, $f$ is probably going to look reverse-sigmoid, or similar to $f''$
Think about whether $f$ will be increasing or decreasing - why do you think so?

Comment: I said in general, but can i associate with concave or increasing(decreasing)?

Comment: If $f'$ is convex, then $f''$ is increasing and $f'''$ is positive.  We do not have a standard name for what this means about $f$ itself, because this property has not (so far) been useful for anything.

Comment: can it be conditions which can be talked about $f$?

Comment: Or, in addition to the assume the question, is there any other condition which can be talked about $f$?

Comment: I think I already answered you:
$f$ is probably going to look reverse-sigmoid, or similar to $f′′$ Think about whether $f$ will be increasing or decreasing - why do you think so?

Comment: how can I prove it?

Answer (score 2):

If $f'$ is convex on $\left]1,+\infty\right[$, then the running average
$$g\colon \left]1,+\infty \right[ \to \mathbb{R} : t \mapsto \frac{1}{t-1}\int_{1}^{t}f'(x)dx$$ is convex. (Hint: you may use the technique in [Running average of a convex function is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194384/running-average-of-a-convex-function-is-convex) to prove this). Since, for every $t >1$, we have $g(t) = (f(t)-f(1))/(t-1)$, one may conclude that 
$$\frac{f(t)-f(1)}{t-1} \text{ is convex on } \left]1,+\infty\right[.$$
Moreover, if $f(1)>0$, then $f(1)/(t-1)$ is convex (second-order test), and thus, you get $f(t)/(t-1)$ is convex.